# Is RVM better than compiling Ruby from source?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I understand the benefits of RVM (multiple ruby versions, etc...) but it seems odd to me that the best way to install ruby would be to use an unsupported installation agent.

Any thoughts?

Comment: What about RVM is unsupported? The author of the program is very responsive and updates it regularly.

Comment: Use [rbenv](https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv) and [ruby-build](https://github.com/sstephenson/ruby-build). Seriously it's a pleasure to work with. Nothing is better than this combo. Everyone that switched from rvm to rbenv will tell the same.

Comment: Is there anything better or more optimized than compiling from source? Especially since RVM makes it so painless to compile and install.

Comment: The Tin Man is correct and Wayne will also post comments here on SO at times.

Comment: I agree with @Delba, anyone who has made the move from rvm to rbenv will agree it's considerably nicer to use.

Answer (score 8):

RVM *does* compile Ruby from source.

http://rvm.io/rubies/installing/

EDIT: in RVM 1.16 an option was added to install from binary packages when available